# How to add inputs to a redirect after form?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a form that, upon submitting, I want to process, and then redirect the user to a validation page.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_validation_list = []
    for key in request.form:
        processed_field = process_somehow(request, key)
        form_validation_list.append(processed_field)

    return render_template('foo.validate_form',
                           form_validation_list=form_validation_list)
```

In similar cases, I use `redirect(url_for('foo.validate_form', variableA=something, variableB=something_else))`, but I don't want `form_validation_list` to show up as GET variables. In the current case where I'm using `render_template`, I get a `TemplateNotFound` exception, but there is certainly a file at `templates/foo/validate_form.html`. I'm not sure if it's clear what I'm trying to do.  If it is, is it clear what's causing the problem?  I will add more information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`render_template('foo.validate_form' ...),` will try to find the `foo.validate_form` template file under `/templates` folder, not at `.../foo/validate_form.html`.

[link to render_template's documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates)